# civiCRM: Resource Limit Is Reached

Tags: configuration

when I load the data from the Excel sheet, I have discovered that civiCRM makes excessive use of resources; how to set civi so that this does not happen? Thanks

Comment: What data are you loading?  How many fields & records are you trying to import?

Comment: Hi Aidan, I'm importing from a CSV file: name, surname, e-mail of 7 individuals

Comment: It shouldn't get anywhere near resource limits on a tiny file like that.  I'm wondering whether there is something like a permissions problem getting misreported as a resource issue.  What dedupe rule are you using?  Have you tried 'No Duplicate checking' ?

Comment: I tried now with. "No duplicate checks" but equally the message is:
Resource Limit Is Reached
The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it is exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

Comment: Might be easier to continue this on Mattermost

Comment: what is Mattermost ? Thanks

Comment: https://chat.civicrm.org - create yourself an account and post something in 'town square' or 'user-support' & include a link to this question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79437/discussion-between-simonetta-officinecollegate-and-aidan).

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do in CiviCRM AFAIK, this depends on the configuration of the server where CiviCRM is running.
And I assume you mean you are importing data from a CVS file, and you do not do that every day.

Comment: Thanks ErikH - CiviCooP.  Yes, I do not do it every day, but when the amount of data, even if only a few at a time, often comes a message like this: "** Resource Limit Is Reached ** The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it is exceeded resource limit. Please try again later " my provider says that it is civiCRM that consumes a lot of resources when importing data and says it should probably be set differently, about this problem

Comment: I disagree with him. CiviCRM might use a lot of resources for importing, but that is almost impossible to avoid if you are importing many records. In my experience I only encounter this problem if I try to import a few thousand of contacts? But it could well be that you only bought a limited space and that you will need to upgrade to a more expensive hosting contract. Alternative is that you develop or get someone to develop a specific import if you need to do this often.